# Equivalent of [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] for iphone / iOS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I've been poring through Apple documentation for some time now but haven't found an iOS equivalent of the `sharedWorkspace` object that one can get from `NSWorkspace` in AppKit. Basically, I just want the `runningApplications` method from it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't have this list in iOS.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such method or analogue. This information is "off limits" on iOS.