# Open an application from another (iOS)

Tags: ios, ipad, applescript, nsworkspace

I read that there is nothing like NSWorkspace for iOS

[Equivalent of NSWorkspace for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518223/equivalent-of-nsworkspace-sharedworkspace-runningapplications-for-iphone-i)

Unfortunately, I wanted a button in my app that can run some others applications (in background). Is it possible without NSWorkspace ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first problem is that you can't run applications in the background in the same way that you can on the Mac.

But, assuming that just launching an app is enough, the answer is: it depends. The other app would need a URL scheme defined. Not all do, unfortunately. Then you just call `[UIApplication openURL:]`.

Comment: To be more precise, I want to send data to an app aimed at different things (like configuring the network).
Maybe I should run a script instead ?

Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Unfortunately the URL scheme is pretty much the only inter-process communication method. Forking a new process isn't an option on iOS.