# Open an iphone app using another app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open an application from another (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926668/open-an-application-from-another-ios)

I want to open my app using another app (also created by me) on a click of a button if it is installed on iPhone.
How I can do it??

Comment: URL Scheme http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926668/open-an-application-from-another-ios

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a custom URL scheme in the Info.plist of the app to be launched. Then in the app that does the launching, you use `UIApplication openURL:` passing in a URL with your other app's custom URL scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following methods

```
- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;

- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url;
```

Where url should be the `URL_SCHEME` specified by you in the build settings (`info.plist`) for the app you want to open.