# URLScheme in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to use an URL scheme in My iPhone app. I want open the application from another one.

Is

```
[UIApplication openURL:]
```

the correct method for doing it?

Comment: That is the correct API to use, but of course when you use it you need to provide a URL with the correct scheme for the other app.

Comment: @OP: You man don't make the effort to hit the quality standard here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open an iphone app using another app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116671/open-an-iphone-app-using-another-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Below Tutorial its help for you.  [iOS SDK: Working with URL Schemes](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/)